# I have disabled comments in my blog, yet am seeing this file blocking my pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have disabled the comment section totally from my blog on all posts and pages., yet pagespeed insights show me that the following error.

```
Consider marking your touch and wheel event listeners as `passive` to improve your page's scroll performance.
```

`/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=5.7.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deregister the JS to avoid its inclusion.

Add this code to the `functions.php` file of your template.

```
function remove_unused_js(){
    wp_deregister_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
add_action('init','remove_unused_js');
```